# Debugging and killing apps on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, debugging, macos, crash

Hey all, I'm in the process of debugging a C++ app on mac os 10.5. Occasionally, I'll do something bad and cause a segfault or an otherwise illegal operation. This results in the app hanging for a while, and eventually a system dialog notifying me of the crash. The wait time between the "hang" and the dialog is significant; a few minutes. If I try to force quit the application or `kill -9` it from the command line nothing happens. If I start the app from the debugger (gdb), upon a crash I get back to gdb prompt and can exit the process cleanly. That's not ideal though as gdb is slow to load.

Anyway, can you guys recommend something? Is there a way to disable the crash reporting mechanism in OS X?

Thanks.

**Update 1**: 
Here're the zombies that are left over from an XCode execution. Apparently xcode can't stop 'em properly either.

```
  1 eightieight@eightieights-MacBook-Pro:~$ ps auxw|grep -i Reader
  2 eightieight   28639   0.0  0.0   599828    504 s004  R+    2:54pm   0:00.00 grep -i reader
  3 eightieight   28288   0.0  1.1  1049324  45032   ??  UEs   2:46pm   0:00.89 /Users/eightieight/workspace/spark/spark/reader/browser/build/Debug/Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/Reader
  4 eightieight   28271   0.0  1.1  1049324  45036   ??  UEs   2:45pm   0:00.89 /Users/eightieight/workspace/spark/spark/reader/browser/build/Debug/Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/Reader
  5 eightieight   28146   0.0  1.1  1049324  44996   ??  UEs   2:39pm   0:00.90 /Users/eightieight/workspace/spark/spark/reader/browser/build/Debug/Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/Reader
  6 eightieight   27421   0.0  1.1  1049328  45024   ??  UEs   2:29pm   0:00.88 /Users/eightieight/workspace/spark/spark/reader/browser/build/Debug/Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/Reader
  7 eightieight   27398   0.0  1.1  1049324  45044   ??  UEs   2:28pm   0:00.90 /Users/eightieight/workspace/spark/spark/reader/browser/build/Debug/Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/Reader
```

Comment: Are you using XCode? If so, you shouldn't be seeing the Crash Reporter dialog. Also, are you building a GUI-based application or just a console application?


Edit: incidentally, in case you are using XCode, if you get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error while running a GUI app in XCode, you can simply press the stop icon to immediately terminate the running app.

Comment: Yeah, if I run my apps within XCode or gdb, everything works correctly. When I get a segfault, the app drops back into the debugger and everything is great. However if I run the app from the console it seems to hang forever.

Comment: How are you invoking the app? Typically if an app goes down hard, game over, the process is dead. However, if you've managed to invoke it from some other environment, perhaps some resources to that process are held open and it can't let go just yet and you're waiting for the parent process to do something first (and it may be having the problem detecting something went awry).

Comment: I'm invoking it from the command line. It's a unit test suite (gtest) that links with Qt. It's a console app, so I run it like one.

Comment: Try to profile it using the "Activity Monitor" instrument. Perhaps you'll find that some other process goes crazy once yours crash?

Comment: The 'UEs' in the ps listing indicates that the processes are in an uninterruptable wait state and trying to exit.  Googling around, seems like killing their parents might be an option, but otherwise you're 'stuck'.  When your application crashes is it accessing some resource external to your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [CrashReporterPrefs app](http://www.macosxhints.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=114974) that comes with XCode (search for it with Spotlight; should be in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities`).  That can be to set to Server Mode to disable the application 'Unexpectedly Quit' dialog too.

Here's [another suggestion](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20091230100541242):

```
sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/Problem\ Reporter.app
```

To re-enable, do the following:

```
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Problem\ Reporter.app
```

It might be that the application is dumping a large core file - you'd probably notice the effect on available disk space though.  You can switch off core dumping using

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.coredump=0
```

Reactivate by setting `=1`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this already. The dialog no longer popups but there's still the delay..

Comment: I would not advise the `chmod` approach.  Modifying system files or permissions is asking for trouble.  The Prefs app will do what you ask.

Comment: @gavinb - agreed; reordered suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/15/disable-the-crash-reporter-dialog-in-mac-os-x/) from osxdaily.com says you just need to type:

`defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none`

in the terminal.  Don't know if that will fix the delay though.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

in /System/Library/CoreServices:

```
----------    1 root  wheel    56752 11 Aug  2009 ReportPanic
```

That must've been from my earlier attempts to disable the annoying report dialog. Live and learn. :]